# Template Tag not available in real Cron Jobs

Tags: cron

I have very simple file with one line:

```
echo file_get_contents( get_template_directory_uri().'/scheduler.php' );
```

This file is called by cpanel cron using php -q. When I put full link without get_template_directory_uri function everything works fine, with this function cron returns Call to undefined function `get_template_directory_uri()`

Comment: Are you usig a child theme? If yes try using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of template directory

Comment: Nope there is no child theme

Comment: what is the cron file you're using? It sounds like you're trying to use WordPress APIs without including WordPress ( there's no magic autoloader here )

Comment: Also, what is your cron script trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

When you run things on the CLI (which is pretty much where Cronjob and [runwhen](http://code.dogmap.org/runwhen/) jobs are running), then you don't have access to some things like some server or request variable contents, etc. What you need to do is fire up WP Core. Else you won't have access to the full WP API.

One method would be to use the [wp-cron](/questions/tagged/wp-cron) API from core, but disable WP internal (virtual/fake) Cron system by setting

```
define( 'DISABLE_WP_CRON', TRUE );
```

in your `wp-config.php` file. Then target [`~/wp-cron.php`] directly - where `~` would be your domain. Keep in mind that you might need to set the proper subdomain or subdirectory when you are running things in a Multisite/Network setup.

WordPress loads the whole core from within this file and then runs every defined (virtual) cron job during the *real* cron job.

Where it won't work (opening line inside `/wp-cron.php`):

```
// No connection to the browser/client needed
ignore_user_abort( TRUE );

if (
    ! empty( $_POST )
    OR defined( 'DOING_AJAX' )
    OR defined( 'DOING_CRON' )
)
    die();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to load WordPress first!

```
require 'path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php';
```

Comment: You are right it works if I include this. Is there any way to get dynamic path?

Comment: from where? short of searching the entire file system that isnt answerable without more information

Comment: I want to install theme on different servers without manually changing path to wp-load.php file.

Comment: @user1756097 Please be more specific - provide additional info with an edit to your question.